# Unable to resolve class java$lang$Enum

Tags: java, groovy

Ok, so this one has me stumped, and the only answer I got from the person who wrote the code in the first place was "yeah, that happens sometimes"...

We have an application written entirely using the Groovy framework. (The application is a Play! plugin, but I think that's irrelevant.) Unfortunately, very occasionally when we start the system up and send requests we get the following error:

```
file:/path_to_file/Language.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class java$lang$Enum 
 @ line 6, column 1.
   public enum Language {
   ^

file:/path_to_file/Language.groovy: -1: unable to resolve class java$lang$Enum 
     @ line -1, column -1.
2 errors
```

As you can see, Language.groovy is just a simple enum; it defines some enum values, some static helper methods for common operations, etc. **Why am I getting a "unable to resolve class java$lang$Enum, and only rarely?**

Unfortunately, Google has failed to enlighten me as to a possible source. I'm ashamed to admit I even turned to Bing for help, with expected results. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what version of Play? How do you "start the system up"? Why the spring tag?

Comment: @tim_yates I don't know (recently started on the project), I don't know (because this secret is closely guarded by system administrators), and because I though Spring was involved but I'll remove the tag now. Why yes, this is a wonderful place to work at, why do you ask? ;) This error seems to only occur when sending in requests after the system started up, and the only current work-around we have is to restart the system.

Comment: I vaguely remember encountering this issue. If i recall, it happened because we were having a classpath issue. something like having either 2 versions of Groovy in the classpath or some other library. Maybe that will be a helpful hint. Sorry I can't recall more details.